# Is it possible to disable opening a new tab or window in browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

My application is online testing. When user clicks the browser button, it goes to directly to my online exam page. User should not be able to open a new tab or window in the browser. Is it possible to disable a new tab or window in the browser using JavaScirpt?

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If it was possible, it could be easily abused by malicious sites, and wouldn't really solve your problem—someone could use another device, for example their phone.

Comment: Is it not possible when the website hosted in the internal server.

Comment: @sathish No.​‌​

Comment: @sathish it's not possible via JS _period_.

Comment: Is it possible to open the new tab and its redirect to some other page.

Comment: @sathish No.​‌​

Comment: @sathish stop thinking of this as doable through JS. It's not. You cannot cripple an _entire browser_ in the way you intend. If it was possible, then malicious websites would already be using it, as Gothdo said. And if malicious websites did it, then browsers would have stepped up to stop them and disable that. As it happens, browsers just don't give that powers to websites to begin with.